How to create a SwiftUI wrapper around UIPageViewController that works in full screen and when rotated?
Apple released some new SwiftUI modifiers for ScrollView in iOS 17 that allow for paginated scrolling, but I need something that will work in iOS 15 and later.

Here's a wrapper around UIPageViewController that I was able to make. Note that it's specifically tailored for my use-case, which is displaying SwiftUI views in a UIPageViewController in full screen within a 16x9 frame, and which can be rotated as your device rotates, and supports iOS 15 and later.
Credit to Sergey Pekar for providing the basis for this solution here.
struct PagingView<Page: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  /// The index of the currently visible page
  @Binding var currentIndex: Int

  let stopCondition: (_ index: Int) -> Bool
  let pageFor: (_ index: Int) -> Page

  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
      transitionStyle: .scroll,
      navigationOrientation: .vertical,
      options: nil
    )

    pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
    pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

    if let startingViewController = context.coordinator.createPage(for: currentIndex) {
      pageViewController.setViewControllers(
        [startingViewController],
        direction: .forward,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
      )
    }

    return pageViewController
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
    context.coordinator.view = self

    let previousIndex = context.coordinator.currentIndexCached
    if
      let nextPage = context.coordinator.createPage(for: currentIndex),
      // Do not change page if the update did not effect the currentIndex.
      previousIndex != currentIndex,
      let visibleViewController = uiViewController.viewControllers?.first,
      let singlePageViewController = visibleViewController as? SinglePageViewController<Page>,
      // Do not change page if update was caused by the user swiping to another page.
      singlePageViewController.index != currentIndex
    {
      uiViewController.setViewControllers(
        [nextPage],
        direction: currentIndex > previousIndex ? .forward : .reverse,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
      )
    }
    context.coordinator.currentIndexCached = currentIndex
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self, currentIndexCached: currentIndex) }

  class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    var view: PagingView
    var currentIndexCached: Int // To detect if currentIndex has changed in updateUIViewController

    init(_ pageViewController: PagingView, currentIndexCached: Int) {
      self.view = pageViewController
      self.currentIndexCached = currentIndexCached
    }

    func pageViewController(
      _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
      viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController
    ) -> UIViewController? {
      let nextIndex = view.currentIndex - 1
      guard !view.stopCondition(nextIndex) else { return nil }
      return createPage(for: nextIndex)
    }

    func pageViewController(
      _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
      viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController
    ) -> UIViewController? {
      let nextIndex = view.currentIndex + 1
      guard !view.stopCondition(nextIndex) else { return nil }
      return createPage(for: nextIndex)
    }

    func pageViewController(
      _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
      didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
      previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
      transitionCompleted completed: Bool
    ) {
      let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first
      if completed, let visiblePage = visibleViewController as? SinglePageViewController<Page> {
        view.currentIndex = visiblePage.index
      }
    }

    fileprivate func createPage(for index: Int) -> SinglePageViewController<Page>? {
      SinglePageViewController(index: index, content: view.pageFor(index))
    }
  }
}

private class SinglePageViewController<Content: View>: UIViewController {
  let index: Int
  let content: Content

  private var contentController: UIViewController?

  init(index: Int, content: Content) {
    self.index = index
    self.content = content

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("This VC is intended for SwfitUI use init(index:, content:) instead")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let contentController = PageContentViewController(index: index, content: content)
    self.contentController = contentController
    addChild(contentController)
    view.addSubview(contentController.view)
    contentController.didMove(toParent: self)

    configureContentFrame(sizeForCentering: view.bounds.size)
  }

  override func viewWillTransition(
    to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator
  ) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    // This seems to be the most efficient place to update the frame when the device is rotated.
    // But it only works in iOS 16 and newer.
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
      configureContentFrame(sizeForCentering: size)
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Must update frame here in iOS 15
    if #unavailable(iOS 16.0) {
      configureContentFrame(sizeForCentering: view.bounds.size)
    }
  }

  private func configureContentFrame(sizeForCentering: CGSize) {
    // Setting the frame from the UIView (rather than from the SwiftUI view) is necessary for
    // interface orientation changes to update the view correctly.

    let aspectRatio: CGFloat = 16/9

    let width = {
      if UIApplication.shared.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
      } else {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height * aspectRatio
      }
    }()

    let height = {
      if UIApplication.shared.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait {
        return width * aspectRatio
      } else {
        return width / aspectRatio
      }
    }()

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    contentController?.view.frame = frame

    contentController?.view.center = CGPoint(
      x: sizeForCentering.width / 2, y: sizeForCentering.height / 2
    )
  }
}

private class PageContentViewController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
  var index: Int

  init(index: Int, content: Content) {
    self.index = index
    super.init(rootView: content)
    _disableSafeArea = true
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
  }

  @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("This VC is intended for SwfitUI use init(index:, content:) instead")
  }
}

#Preview {
  struct PagingViewPreview: View {
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
      PagingView(
        currentIndex: $currentIndex,
        // Here you can limit number of pages depending on index or just return false if you
        // want infinite pages.
        stopCondition: { index in abs(index) > 10 },
        pageFor: { index in
          // Create your date or whatever according to current index
          Text(
            Calendar.current
              .date(byAdding: .day, value: index, to: Date())!
              .formatted(.dateTime)
          )
        }
      )
    }
  }

  return PagingViewPreview()
}

For how to implement UIApplication.shared.interfaceOrientation to detect the interface orientation, see my SO Answer to SwiftUI force device rotation programmatically
